# Uninstall nagios that has been manually installed through source

Tags: centos, centos6, nagios, uninstall

I installed nagios through [this guide](http://www.tecmint.com/install-nagios-in-linux/) which works fine, but now i'd like to uninstall it altogether. Could you guide me what i need to delete as i cannot see an uninstallation routine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just do the steps in reverse(ish) order:

1. Stop the Nagios daemon
2. Remove the web conf, if you installed it
3. Remove the user and group that you added for Nagios
4. Remove the init script
5. Remove /usr/local/nagios directory

Then, next time you want to test a new version of Nagios, you use a VM so you can revert to a snapshot.

Answer (score -1):

added to above process:

`find / -name "nagios*" -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: Using this from the root of the filesystem might be a bit extreme; better would be to suggest to the OP that the `find` command start with the Nagios installation directory.  Also, the suggested answer would be improved with some explanation for why this would cover everything requested.

Comment: A part of this command is helpful to find all directories .... because in normal mode there is an error to delete a directory

Comment: I had to use this to get everything nagios removed. Wish they learned how to package their software properly.